# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 error in discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I get this error:

```
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '<@256430125040533504>'
```

For this Code:

```
     @client.command(pass_context=True)
async def give(self, user_id: discord.User.id, money: int):
    user_add_xp(user_id, money)
    embed = discord.Embed(description='{0} hat {1}EXP bekommen'.format(discord.User.name, money))
    await self.client.say(embed=embed)
```

This Command should give an User The said amount of money
the command is or should be
.give (name) (amount of money)

Comment: @DenisAscheri which error?

Comment: are you sure you want it `user_id: discord.User.id`?

Comment: How are you invoking this command?

Comment: Is this command inside a cog? If it isn't in a class, why is the first argument `self`?  If it is in a class, why are you passing the context without giving it its own argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the rest of your codes structure it's difficult to say exactly how this command should be structured.  Below is my best guess.

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord import User

client = Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def give(ctx, user: User, money: int):
    user_add_xp(user.id, money)
    embed = discord.Embed(description='{0} hat {1}EXP bekommen'.format(user.name, money))
    await client.say(embed=embed)

client.run("token")
```

Note that I don't use `self.client` because this coroutine is not a method of a class with a `client` attribute.  Instead, the first argument to the command is the invocation context.